# Correct way to instantiate class so I'm able to validate path chains in certificate

Tags: java, cryptography, x509certificate, xml-dsig

I have 3d party library(sdk for Kalkan provider). Part of this library checks certificate paths I believe. Problem is I should pass two parameters to instantiate class correctly that I could use one of its method I need.

Here's code:

```
final PKIXCertPathReviewer checker = new PKIXCertPathReviewer(cp, params);
boolean test = checker.isValidCertPath();
```

Here's part of constructor:

```
public PKIXCertPathReviewer(CertPath certPath, PKIXParameters params)
```

About task a bit. I have signed document by client certificate. I want to validate path in client's certificate. So I have client's X509Certificate instance of certificate, one middle certificate and one root certificate. Last two are files in cer format on disk. As I understand I should combine all those three certificates together. If someone showed me how to create those *cp* and *params* it would be really helpfull. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's better solution:

```
Provider p = ProviderUtil.loadKalkanProvider();
X509Certificate ca = X509Util.loadX509Certificate("/tmp/ca/root_ca_rsa.cer", p);
X509Certificate nca = X509Util.loadX509Certificate("/tmp/ca/root_nca_rsa.cer", p);
X509Certificate cert = X509Util.loadX509Certificate("/tmp/cert/user.cer", p);
X509CRL crl = X509Util.loadX509CRL("/tmp/ca/rsa.crl", p);
X509CRL rcrl = X509Util.loadX509CRL("/tmp/ca/root_rsa.crl", p);
ArrayList<X509Extension> list = new ArrayList<X509Extension>();
list.add(nca);
list.add(cert);
list.add(crl);
list.add(rcrl);
CollectionCertStoreParameters certStoreParameters = new CollectionCertStoreParameters(list);
CertStore certStore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", certStoreParameters, p);
CertPathBuilder builder = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX", p);
// проверка до корневого CA, можно сократить до промежуточного NCA
TrustAnchor anchor = new TrustAnchor(ca, null);
Set<TrustAnchor> anchors = new HashSet<TrustAnchor>();
anchors.add(anchor);
X509CertSelector selector = new X509CertSelector();
// задаем параметры для селектора конечного сертификата или можно указать полное соответствие сертификата
//selector.setSerialNumber(cert.getSerialNumber());
//selector.setIssuer(cert.getIssuerX500Principal());
selector.setCertificate(cert);
PKIXBuilderParameters builderParameters = new PKIXBuilderParameters(anchors, selector);
// если не добавляли список CRL, то надо отключить проверку
//builderParameters.setRevocationEnabled(false);
builderParameters.addCertStore(certStore);
builderParameters.setSigProvider(p.getName());
PKIXCertPathBuilderResult builderResult = (PKIXCertPathBuilderResult) builder.build(builderParameters);
System.out.println(builderResult);
// можем закодировать и сохранить полученный путь в форматах PkiPath/PKCS7/PEM
//builderResult.getCertPath().getEncoded("PkiPath");
```

Answer (score 1):

So I've managed to solve my problem. Here's code if someone would have the same problems as me.

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", KalkanProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
java.security.cert.Certificate rootCertificate = /*root certificate*/;
java.security.cert.Certificate clientCertificate = /*client certificate*/;
List mylist = new ArrayList();
mylist.add(clientCertificate);
CertPath cp = cf.generateCertPath(mylist);
TrustAnchor rootAnchor = new TrustAnchor((X509Certificate) rootCertificate, null);
Set<TrustAnchor> trustStore = new HashSet<>();
trustStore.add(rootAnchor);
if (null != /*chain contains middle cert besides root*/) {
    java.security.cert.Certificate middleCertificate = /*middle certificate*/;
    TrustAnchor middleAnchor = new TrustAnchor((X509Certificate) middleCertificate, null);
    trustStore.add(middleAnchor);
}
PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(trustStore);
params.setRevocationEnabled(false);//true - if you need ocsp validation
final PKIXCertPathReviewer checker = new PKIXCertPathReviewer(cp, params);
errors = checker.getErrors();
boolean result = checker.isValidCertPath();
```